# Option select menu not working on android? Cannot diagnose as to why

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, wordpress

I have a select menu on one of my sites thats is currently not working on android chrome browser. It works perfectly in iOS and on desktop for both mac and windows as well as using an android useragent. The options menu opens for a brief second of time and disappears not allowing any changes to be made in the field.

Im a little confused as to how to resolve this issue:

The field is as follows;
It is initially disabled unless a radio button is selected hence the disabled="disabled"

```
<select id="MoreDays" class="all-durations day" name="duration" disabled="disabled" size="5">
            <option value="8 days">8 days</option>
            <option value="9 days">9 days</option>
            <option value="10 days">10 days</option>
            <option value="11 days">11 days</option>
            <option value="12 days">12 days</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, where a select wasn't behaving as expected on my android device. Purging/clearing my sites cache worked well for me!